# Running Spring boot application in IntelliJ gives white label error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat, intellij-idea

I am trying to run Spring boot web application in IntelliJ which gives me whitelabel error. However, I am able to run the application with eclipse and also external tomcat server.

I have the context mapping available where it is returned from the application but webpage always shows WhiteLabel Error 404.
Please suggest how does the same application works in eclipse and external tomcat but not with IntelliJ.
I am using IntelliJ community edition v 2020.2.3
web pages are available in webapp folder.

Comment: Do you deploy acpplicatoin to Tomcat server as a war archive? What is the application you are using in IDE to run the app? Please add screenshots. Note that IntelliJ IDEA Community edition does not support Tomcat server.

Comment: I am running from the IDE itself, so using the internal tomcat server for spring boot application

Answer (score 0):

First download xammp server to your machine. Then run your spring boot application. I used this method to run my spring boot application. But keep in mind that IntelliJ community doesn't directly support to spring-boot. You have to use IntelliJ ultimate for that.